# .animate jQuery function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, html-lists

I have searched the solution to the following. I'm trying to animate list items using jQuery. Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({paddingLeft: '+=15px'}, 200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({paddingLeft: '-=15px'}, 200);
    });
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
ul {
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

I've checked that I'm calling the script properly.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: ^ At jsfiddle.net, he means.

Comment: Works fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/eqYxE/

Comment: Try something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/P77kq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Commenters were correct, first code was flawed. Edited, I think this is what you're after?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).animate({paddingLeft: '+15px'}, 200)
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).animate({paddingLeft: '-15px'}, 200);
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/P77kq/3

Comment: Looks to me like your code is the one that is missing closing brackets ?

Comment: Yes, your code is missing brackets. And the original wrong code in the question has been fixed.

Comment: Code isn't missing brackets O.o

Comment: Yes it is, the first function is'nt closed! The reason it works is because you close it at the end, and the second function is suddenly just an unnamed function inside the first, which defeats the point entirely.

Comment: Ugh, missed that. Fixed, I think this is what he wants?